# Create List<Object> from List<List<Object>> in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have List<List> and I want to create List where I have all cars from List<List>. There is any way in Kotlin to create that (using map or something)? I don't want to create new list and add items in loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr [`List.flatten()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flatten.html)

Let's say your `List<List<Car>>` is called `carLists`, then you can simply call `val cars: List<Car> = carLists.flatten()` if you want to have a single list containing all the cars from the list of lists of cars.

Code only:

```kotlin
val carLists: List<List<Car>> = … // created or received
val cars = carLists.flatten()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val listOfLists: List<List<Int>> = listOf(listOf(1, 2, 3), listOf(4, 5))
```

One way would be to use [flatten function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flatten.html). This function just flattens the inner lists

```
val flatten: List<Int> = listOfLists.flatten() //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But if you need to do some transformation as well as flattening the list then you can do it with [flatMap()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html):

```
val flatMap: List<Int> = listOfLists.flatMap { it.map { it*2 } } //[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```